# Uri on Activity.onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)

Tags: android, android-intent, media

I have some doubts on the reliability of content providers in Android.

## 1 - Is it possible for different `Document`s having the same Uri?

For instance. A user has 2 images in the device:

```
content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%AAAAA
```

and

```
content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%BBBBB
```

Supposing a scenario where `AAAAA` would point to a file, then the user erases that file.

User then creates a new file in the system, and that new file receives the `AAAAA` Uri.

### Can this scenario happen?

Or are they sequentially generated so that `CCCCC` `DDDDD`etc.. gets created first, in a way that I can trust Uri's to always point to the same file instance (or null if no document can be found by that Uri)?

## 2 - Is it possible for an Uri pointing to a document that has been significantly altered?

Can a document, that once was Audio, and now is an Image, have the same identifier that once had? I do not mean that the user has changed the file content, but rather an implicit intent gave me a Uri, can I trust that Uri to be unique, for that document in that device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can this scenario happen?

Yes.

> Can a document, that once was Audio, and now is an Image, have the same identifier that once had?

Yes.

Note that the same thing holds true for pretty much everything else in computers. For example, a URL can be reused to point to different Web content, including content with a different MIME type.

Comment: I did not understood the editted: "For example, a URL can be reused to point". ->  `Activity.onActivityResult(args)` can only happen once, with an argument that is immutable (`final`) for that function scope. Not only that, but source states that `In the interest of performance, this class performs little to no validation. Behavior is undefined for invalid input. This class is very forgiving--in the face of invalid input, it will return garbage rather than throw an exception unless otherwise specified.`

Comment: @Bonatti: "I did not understood" -- you have no guarantee that the URL `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36922714/uri-on-activity-onactivityresultint-requestcode-int-resultcode-intent-data` will never change its content (for example, it changed when I answered the question and changed again when you posted your comment). You have no guarantee that this URL will always point to `text/html` content. The same premise holds true for `Uri` values in Android. With regards to `onActivityResult()`, I fail to see what that has to do with the implementation of a `ContentProvider`.

Comment: `You have no guarantee that this URL will always point to text/html content.` In the case of HTTP requests, dont I the "requester" can ask for the expected result? Likewise, in Android, an `Uri` is not obliged to answer a unique value for each document built on that request (since all Uris are just Strings)?

Comment: @Bonatti: "dont I the "requester" can ask for the expected result?" -- sure. And with a `Uri`, you call `getType()` on a `ContentResolver` to get the expected result. "an Uri is not obliged to answer a unique value for each document" -- correct, just as a URL is not obliged to answer a unique value for each document. A `ContentProvider` is very similar to a Web server in these regards.