# Intent ACTION_GET_CONTENT returns uri even for deleted files

Tags: android, file, android-intent, android-contentprovider

I am trying to read pdf files in the android app.

Fire following intent to get URI.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("application/pdf");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
startActivityForResult(intent, PDF_FILE_SELECTOR_INTENT_ID);
```

Problem is, the `Downloads` folder also shows old files that I have deleted.
Also, when I select those files a valid `URI` is returned in `onActivityResult()`. When I create `File` from `URI` and check `exists()` it returns `false` which makes sense as I have already deleted the file from the `Downloads` folder.

How can I make sure that the `Downloads` folder shown on `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` shows only files which are currently present and not deleted ones?

Thanks.

Comment: [This is the intented behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36922714/uri-on-activity-onactivityresultint-requestcode-int-resultcode-intent-data). URI(s) are not updated instantly, so, they may point to null, non-existant, or even different kind of targets (audio, images, etc.)

Comment: Wouldn't you need a content provider to do this for you?

Comment: in which device you are testing. And what is android os version?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

> intent.setType("application/pdf"); use the **Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES** in the putExtra

**In Java:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.setType("*/*");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, new String[] {
                "application/pdf", // .pdf
        });
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

**In Kotlin**

```
startActivityForResult(
        Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT).apply {
            addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
            type = "*/*"
            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, arrayOf(
                    "application/pdf", // .pdf
            ))
        },
        REQUEST_CODE
      )
```

**Update**:  Actual Download Folder & "Downloads" folder different in this case.

Download is for your actual downloaded files
Downloads is a history folder behaves like a short-cut and it's not cleared automatically when the actual file pointed to is manually removed. This might be most likely an expect behavior.

In your case , you need to hide the downloads folder ( still you can use Download). using this line of code will show "Internal storage"  by default:

```
intent.putExtra("android.content.extra.SHOW_ADVANCED", true);
```

Comment: For me, with the code, the old already deleted folders in Downloads is still shown. How to refresh?

Answer (score 0):

Call `addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)` to your Intent as recommended here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_GET_CONTENT

Comment: with CATEGORY_OPENABLE still shows a lot of previously deleted files...